# Scrapy: retain original order of scraped items in the output

Tags: python, scrapy

I have the following Scrapy spider to get the status of the pages from the list of urls in the file url.txt

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider
from pegasLinks.items import StatusLinkItem

class FindErrorsSpider(CrawlSpider):
    handle_httpstatus_list = [404,400,401,500]
    name = "findErrors"

    allowed_domains = ["domain-name.com"]
    f = open("urls.txt")
    start_urls = [url.strip() for url in f.readlines()]
    f.close()

    def parse(self, response):
        item = StatusLinkItem()
        item['url'] = response.url
        item['status'] = response.status
        yield item
```

Here's my items.py file:

```
import scrapy

class StatusLinkItem(scrapy.Item):
    url = scrapy.Field()
    status = scrapy.Field()
```

I use the following command to get the output of items in CSV:

```
scrapy crawl findErrors -o File.csv
```

The order of items in the ouput file is different from the order of corresponding urls in urls.txt file. How can I retain the original order or add another field to the items.py with some kind of global variable, which will represent the id of the urls, with which I will be able to restore the original order later?

Comment: Please, fix indentation in your code sample.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not rely on order or urls in `start_urls`.

You can do the following thing. Override [`start_requests`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spider.Spider.start_requests) method in your spider to add something like `index` parameter into [`meta`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html?highlight=request#scrapy.http.Request.meta) dictionary in created `Request` objects.

```
def start_requests(self):
    for index, url in enumerate(self.start_urls):
        yield  Request(url, dont_filter=True, meta={'index': index})
```

Later you can access `meta` in your `parse` function by using [`response.meta`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html?highlight=request#scrapy.http.Response.meta).

Comment: I wish had been implemented by default into *Scrapy*.